# Expanding ladder operators in terms of field operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, s-matrix-theory

In the LSZ reduction formula for calculating the S-matrix of real scalar interacting fields, one of the crucial steps in the derivation is to write the annihilation operator as $$a(\vec{k})=i\int d^3\vec{x} ~e^{ipx}\overset\leftrightarrow{\partial_0} \phi(\vec{x},t)$$
which I am hoping to derive. However in my derivation there is something wrong that I had a hard time spotting, so I am hoping that someone experienced could help me. The main problem is that it seemed like I do not need the canonical momentum to have a formula for $a(\vec{k})$. For free scalar real fields:
$$\phi(x)=\int\frac{d^3\vec{p}}{(2E_p)(2\pi)^3}\left(a(\vec{p})e^{-ipx}+a^\dagger(\vec{p})e^{ipx}\right)\equiv\phi_++\phi_-$$
where the Minkowski metric is diag$(+,-,-,-)$. It is clear that
$$a(\vec{p})=\int d^3\vec{x}~ \phi_+(\vec{x},t)e^{ipx}2E_p$$
and
$$a^\dagger(\vec{p})=\int d^3\vec{x}~ \phi_-(\vec{x},t)e^{-iE_p t+i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}}2E_p$$
In particular, as we know that $a^\dagger(-\vec{p})e^{iE_pt}=a(\vec{p})e^{-iE_pt}$ we are free to write $a^\dagger(\vec{p})$ as
$$a^\dagger(-\vec{p})=a(\vec{p})e^{-2iE_pt}=\int d^3\vec{x}~ \phi_-(\vec{x},t)e^{-iE_p t-i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}}2E_p$$
therefore we obtain an alternative expression for $a(\vec{p})$ as $$a(\vec{p})=\int d^3\vec{x}~ \phi_-(\vec{x},t)e^{ipx}2E_p$$
one can see clearly we could add up the two expressions of $a(\vec{p})$ to obtain
$$a(\vec{p})=\int d ^3\vec{x}\phi(\vec{x},t)e^{ipx}(2E_p)$$
which is wrong.

Edit: I am adding a derivation of the relationship between $a^{\dagger}(\pm \vec{p})$ and $a(\pm\vec{p})$. The physical understanding of which I am uncertain of and therefore will not discuss here.

The integration of the mode expansion of field is $dp_xdp_ydp_z$ therefore when one changes from $\vec{p}$ to $-\vec{p}$ there is a sign change which cancels off with the sign change from integration range, and we obtain
$$\phi(\vec{x},t)=\int \frac{d^3{\vec{p}}}{2E_p(2\pi)^3}a(-\vec{p})e^{-iE_pt}e^{-i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}}+a^\dagger(-\vec{p})e^{iE_pt}e^{i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}}$$
and we only need to equate the Fourier coefficients of each Fourier mode to obtain the proposed relation I mentioned before.

Edit 2: as this is often considered an obvious question I will refrain from posting my answer here, but I did arrive at the correct expression at the end. I would like to warn anyone who see my previous edit on the equality which I claimed to be mathematically valid - it is deadly wrong. The reason is one could not equate Fourier coefficient that way, which is obvious once you write $\phi$ as $\phi_++\phi_-$.

Comment: Already your first expression is wrong. A factor $i$ is missing and $e^{-i px}$ should be replaced by $e^{+ipx}$. (There are more mistakes also below.) Simply start from the corrected first formula, remember $\int d^3 x e^{i \vec{l} \cdot \vec{x}}=(2\pi)^3 \delta^{(3)}(\vec{l})$, $p^0=\sqrt{\vec{p}^2+m^2}$ and $k^0=\sqrt{\vec{k}^2+m^2}$. Do not make unfounded extra assumptions!

Comment: Hi. I have corrected the formula. Thank you for pointing it out. I could start from the correct expression to arrive at the field expansion. What I was trying to do is the reserve process. It would be helpful if you could please point out the mistakes below you mentioned, especially the unfounded extra assumptions part. Thank you.

Comment: Already the formula after "It is clear that..." is simply wrong. There is also no relation between $a(\vec{p})$ and $a^\dagger(-\vec{p})$. $a(\vec{p})$ destroys a particle with momentum $\vec{p}$ and $a^\dagger(-\vec{p})$ creates a particle with momentum $-\vec{p}$! Simply start from the first formula and use my previous hints. Forget the rest!

Comment: I do not understand what is wrong with $a(\vec{p})=\int d^3\vec{x}\phi_{+}(\vec{x},t)e^{ipx}2E_p$, which is nothing other than the inverse Fourier transform of $\phi_+$ containing the negative frequency part of the wave. As for the $a^\dagger(-\vec{p})$ part, it is a direct mathematical equility by substituting the mode expansion of the field by $\vec{p}\to -\vec{p}$.

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up the lines. $a(\vec{p})=\int d^3x \phi_+(t, \vec{x}) e^{ipx} 2 E_\vec{p}$ is correct. But, as I already said, your relation between $a(\vec{p})$ and $a^\dagger(-\vec{p})$ does not exist. You cannot obtain it by the variable transformation $\vec{p} \to -\vec{p}$ in $\phi(x)$ taking into account the time depence of the field. $E_{\vec{p}}$ does NOT change sign under $\vec{p} \to - \vec{p}$.

Comment: Hyperon, please check the editted part of my question, I've added a derivation of the claim.

Comment: LAST comment: Your (new) last formula is (trivially) correct. But the the conclusions you seem to draw from it above are wrong. Please think about it and consider an approach taking into account my previous hints.